# Controllers slugs

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I'm planing to develop mid size website. I want to use  SEO friendly url's like

```
http://foobar.com/category/fun/
http://foobar.com/article/lorem-ipsum.html
```

As you can see I want to use slugs for controllers names.
I intend to implement it in the following way.

One file to handle all requests.

In routes.php

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'my_routes/$1';
```

And then in my_routes with $this->uri->segment I can determinate which controller is requested.

Is it good idea to use just one file (my_routes) for entire website ?

Can you recommend me some better solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's good decision. I do the same in my projects, all routes via index.php and .htaccess file configured to send all URLs on index.php.